# what the problem with "characterIndex" it gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments

I want to change the value of **str** to **str[characterIndex]** but it gives me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined.

and when I delete a letter from the argument, the number 8 changes and if delete all of it except on letter it works.

```js
function FirstReverse(str) {
  let characterIndex;
  for (characterIndex = str.indexOf(str[str.length - 1]); characterIndex >= 0; --characterIndex) {
    str = str[characterIndex];
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(FirstReverse("hello world"));
```

what I want to do is to reverse the order of (str).
in this case output should be : "dlrow olleh"

Comment: 1)What is the expected output of the code? 2)Also `str.indexOf(str[str.length - 1])` will always be `str.length - 1`(if no duplicates). 3) Why you are assigning the whole string to a single character?

Comment: accept/upvote answer if it helped, check [When Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the original string `str` with a char.

When you do `str = str[characterIndex];`, the `str` is overwritten with a single char, then when you access an index in next iteration (index = 9), that index does not exist on this `str`, and `str` is assigned the undefined value.

In next iteartion (index = 8), you are trying to index `str` which is now undefined, that's why the below error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '8' of undefined.

You can fix this by adding a new local var (e.g. `newstr`) and storing the modified string in that.

```js
function FirstReverse(str) {
  let characterIndex, newstr = "";
  for (characterIndex = str.indexOf(str[str.length - 1]); characterIndex >= 0; --characterIndex) {
    newstr += str[characterIndex];
  }
  return newstr;
}
console.log(FirstReverse("hello world"));
```